# Does datasource need to be in prototype scope in spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

When we using spring jdbc , first we define a dataSource bean and  inject it when creating jdbcTemplate object . What I want to know is do we need to define this dataSource in prototype scope. Unless  there  is only one dataSource object for whole application . I think this affects to reduce application performance.

Here is how I have defined dataSouce inside spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="123" />
</bean>
```

In my DAO class I have autowired dataSOurce as below.

```
@Repository
public class RecordDAOImpl {

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = null;

@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

}
```

Let me know what is the best way to define dataSource for spring mvc web application.

Answer (score 3):

> What I want to know is do we need to define this dataSource in prototype scope

No we don't need. I guess it wouldn't be good idea, we can use some kind of connection pool datasource and singleton scope bean.

We can also have multiple databases and provide for each own datasource singleton scoped, there is not any problem with that.

> Let me know what is the best way to define dataSource for spring mvc web application.

There is nothing wrong with defining your data Sources in xml files (although many devs seem to avoid xml). I like to do it using java config, since I feel like its easier to read.

Depending on driver and database it would look more or less like that:

```
@Configuration
class DatasourceConfig {

    @Bean
    DataSource datasource() {
        PGPoolingDataSource dataSource = new PGPoolingDataSource();
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");
        dataSource.setPortNumber(123);
        dataSource.setUser("user");
        dataSource.setMaxConnections(10);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```